# python は改行なしの文法は定義されているか

Tags: python

ruby 文法上改行がなくても記述できますが、 python に改行は必須ですか？

Makefile など、ほかのプログラムから python の(ちょっとした)コマンドを呼ぶ際に、これができるのかできないのか気になったので、質問しています。

Comment: 「改行なしで（複数の文からなる節を持つ）複合文を作る方法」があるか、と云う事でよいですか？ それとも、複合文なしでどこまでやれるか、というチャレンジ（になると思います）でしょうか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

セミコロンである程度はできます。

```
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.version_info)"
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

標準入力の処理など。

```
$ echo "Hello World" | python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().split()[-1])"
World
```

if, forなどの制御構文を使えないので擬似的に実現するのは面倒です。

```
$ python -c "a = input('Y/N? : '); print(['YES', 'NO'][0 if a=='Y' else 1])"
Y/N? : Y
YES

$ python -c "a = input('Y/N? : '); print(['YES', 'NO'][0 if a=='Y' else 1])"
Y/N? : N
NO
```